# Creating an SQL Server connection string without importing a datasource in C#

Tags: c#, sql, windows

I am going off of this tutorial: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlclient  . Instead of adding a data source and a having visual studio compile my connecting string - I want to do it myself. The reason being is that the database will not always be the same and I want this application to be able to use different databases depending on which I point it to.

So how can I manually create the connection string? I am using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: pass the connectionstring to the constructor of SqlConnection...

Comment: Can you give an example of this. I apologize but I am somewhat new to C#.

Comment: The problem is also I am unaware of the format for the connection string.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Go to [connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com/) and find the proper format for your database.

Step 2: Plug in the appropriate values to the connection string.

Step 3: Pass that string to the constructor of `SqlConnection`.

I would also suggest storing your connection string in your app.config/web.config file. You can then modify them easily if needed. The proper format can be found at [MSDN - connectionStrings element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233.aspx). You then change your code to:

```
 SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(
     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStringName"].ConnectionString);
```

Comment: How do I select the table I want to read/write from if it is a remote database?

Comment: @pss1337 - That would be part of your SQL query.

Comment: Gotcha, I forgot it is just like regular SQL statements after I connect to the database. Does this look like it would work, or do I need to pass the connection string differently (test values for pwd,and uname, etc). http://pastebin.com/4Mqq0YZN

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where the connection string is **"compiled"**.

In the code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
    ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.masterConnectionString)
```

`ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.masterConnectionString` is a field and it can be replaced with any other appropriate string.

Answer (score 0):

for SQL Server format of the connection string is

"Data Source = server_address; Initial Catalog = database_name; User ID = UserId; Password = ****;"

save this connection string in a string variable and use with connection object.

either way you can add in web.config file.

```
<ConnectionString>
<add name = "name_of_connecctionString" ConnectionString = "Data Source = server_address;       Initial Catalog = database_name; User ID = UserId; Password = ****;" ProviderName = "system.Data.SqlClient"/>
</ConnectionString>
```

you can change the provider as needed by you.

then in code behind file access this particular connection string using configuration manager.